# How to prevent an access check failed when using .all on records/pointers?

Tags: ada

This is the code that sets up all my pointers and records and stuff.

```ada
     type BSTNode;

     type BSTNodePtr is access BSTNode;

     type BSTNode is record
         key: Key_Type;
         data: Item_Type;
         left, right: BSTNodePtr;
     end record;

     type BSTree is record
        root: BSTNodePtr;
     end record;
```

I have a function that is:

```ada
     function contains(key: Key_Type; t: BSTree) return Boolean is
        temp_node : BSTNodePtr := t.root; 
        right : boolean; 
        left : boolean;
        temp_tree : BSTree;
     begin
       if temp_node.all.key = key then --error occurs
               return true;

       elsif temp_node.all.left /= null and
        temp_node.all.right /= null then

         temp_tree.root := temp_node.all.left;
         left := contains(key, temp_tree);
         temp_tree.root := temp_node.all.right;
           right := contains(key, temp_tree);
         if left = true or right = true then
            return true;
         else
            return false;
         end if;

         else
            return false;
         end if;


     end contains;
```

Every time that I try to do the .all, I get a Constraint error, access check failed. I know that it is because it doesn't know if that code is allocated or not, but I don't know what I would need to do to be able to access it or make it do it anyway without giving the error. If anyone could help or knows what I'm doing incorrectly, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Ada.Containers.Multiway_Trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I needed to have it check to make sure it wasn't null first before I could use the .access. So, I just added an if statement before most of the code. Which makes sense, idk why it took me so long to think of haha.

Answer (score 2):

Good to hear you were able to find a solution! Just as a hint: you could also split the function and simplify the code somewhat to:

```ada
function Contains (Key : Key_Type; N : BSTNode) return Boolean is
begin
   return (N.Key = Key)
     or else ((N.Left  /= null) and then Contains (Key, N.Left.all)) 
     or else ((N.Right /= null) and then Contains (Key, N.Right.all));
end Contains;

function Contains (Key : Key_Type; T : BSTree) return Boolean is
begin
   return (T.Root /= null) and then Contains (Key, T.Root.all);
end Contains;
```

Here, the behavior of the [short-circuit binary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) `and then` is used to prevent the dereferencing of a pointer if it's `null`.